# Install multiple Linux from network

Tags: linux, boot, installation, multiple-computers

For example if I have 4 computers and I want to install Linux to all these, what is the fastest way to install multiple computers at the same time and how ? For example our school has computer classes and if I need to try something which needs multiple computers how can I quickly set them up ? I was thinking that if I create a image first and then somehow install it via network boot ? Suggestions ? Using Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cobbler](http://www.cobblerd.org/).

It has a nice web interface to manage your deployment image and you can create seed and kickstart file to automate install.

You can create system profiles by mac address to automatically choose the good kickstart file.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for though Cobbler doesn't have debian/ubuntu support yet :(

Comment: are you sure? I installed cobbler on ubuntu 12.04 and deploy ubuntu VM with it. The only "Fix" i made is to make ubuntu use kickstart file you have to choose redhat as os. if you don't do that it will try to load a seed file.

Comment: No I am not sure, just read it from cobbler website, but if you managed to do that then I have to try it also..

Answer (score 0):

Likely the best way would be to use Ghost software to create an image of your setup and put it on a portable device of your choice to implement on a new system. Assuming you have one copy you can probably do four computers in under an hour. [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) will do this for you just fine, or you can select whichever one you want.

Just bare in mind you will need to set your IP etc as you go along, since you don't want this mirrored.

Comment: I have to look at this for now because Cobbler doesn't have debian/ubuntu support.

Comment: @Shnigi | I made this suggestion because I was unable to find a network package which works on your desired OS. If you find one do let me know as it would be useful to me very soon.